# How to get specific elements(array) of array using filter in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a certain value; for example, if I got ‘2019’ as this sort_id, I want to get elements which contains ‘2019’ as sort_id
. so I have to get 2 works elements as a result
Further question) does filter function filter arrays from array or just one element from array?

```
export default {
works : [
    {
        works_id: 'works1',
        sort_title: 'years',
        sort: '2019',
        title: 'etd1',
        year: '2019',
    },
    {
        works_id: 'works2',
        sort_title: 'years',
        sort: '2019',
        title: 'etd2',
        year: '2019',
    },
    {
        works_id: 'works3',
        sort_title: 'years',
        sort: '2018',
        title: 'etd1',
        year: '2018',
    }
 ]
}




<template>
 <div class="">
  <div v-for="(o, index) in getWorksImgs" :key="index">
   <div v-for="(a, index) in o" :key="index">
    <img :src="a.mother">
   </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script>
 import StorageWorks from '@/storage/works'

export default {
name: 'Works',
 data() {
   return {
    workImgs : StorageWorks.works,
    sort_id : this.$route.params.sort_id
   }
 },
 computed: {
    getWorksImgs(){
        let worksImgs = this.worksImgs
        worksImgs= worksImgs.filter(w => w.sort === this.sort_id )

        return worksImgs

       }
    }
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code will return you 2 works as you wished for.

```
let filteredArrayOfObjects = this.works.filter(function (item) {
          return item.sort === '2019';
        });
console.log("You will get two objects returned here" + filteredArrayOfObjects)
```

and here it is filtering array of objects based on condition, not array of array.

Comment: i dont get it. can you explain more details? i don't see the difference between this and my code